# SQL Server 2008: ALTER TABLE query 

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, alter

I am getting error for the below code

```
ALTER TABLE ADM_Roles ALTER COLUMN RoleID int IDENTITY (1, 1)
```

Incorrect syntax near the keyword `IDENTITY`.

Comment: [Are you on an edition that supports partitioning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084572/how-to-set-auto-increment-after-creating-a-table-without-any-data-loss/6086661#6086661)

Answer (score 6):

You **cannot** change an existing column into an `IDENTITY` column - you will need to add **a new column** that has the identity flag:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ADM_Roles 
 ADD NewRoleID INT IDENTITY (1, 1)
```

If you need to, you can later on drop the old column and rename the new column to the old name:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ADM_Roles DROP COLUMN RoleID

EXEC sp_rename @objName = 'dbo.ADM_Roles.NewRoleID', 
               @newName = 'RoleID', 
               @objType = 'COLUMN'
```

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN

[You can't alter the existing columns for identity.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/04d69ee6-d4f5-4f8f-a115-d89f7bcbc032)

> You have 2 options,
>
> 1. Create a new table with identity & drop the existing table
> 2. Create a new column with identity & drop the existing column   But
>      take special care when these columns have any constraints / relations.

Example approach:

- In this approach you can’t retain the existing data values on the newly created identity column;
- The identity column will hold the sequence of number

  ```
  Alter Table Names Add Id_new Int Identity(1,1)
  Go

  Alter Table Names Drop Column ID
  Go

  Exec sp_rename 'Names.Id_new', 'ID','Column'
  ```

Answer (score -1):

you have to remove the word "int".

```
ALTER TABLE ADM_Roles ALTER COLUMN RoleId IDENTITY (1, 1);
```