# "Save changes is not permitted" when changing an existing column to be nullable

Tags: sql, ssms, nullable

I've got a SQL Database Table, which has 35 existing records. One of the fields in this table is called `Name`, `nvarchar(100)`, `not null`

However, due to a recent change, I need to make this column nullable.

When I change the column to allow nulls in SQL Server Management Studio, and go to save my changes, I get the following error:

> Saving changes is not permitted. The changes you have made require the
>   following tables to be dropped and re-created

How can I allow this to automatically be dropped and re-created?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I've found the solution. Go to "Tools > Options > Designers > Table and Database Designers":

[image]

Comment: The only thing that's a waste of people's time is marking something as an answer that doesn't actually help someone with the same problem. ;-)

Comment: @Oran Haha, my guess is you've not got the same problem, or else I wouldnt of marked it as answer. Perhaps a different SQL Server version?..

Comment: MS says that re-creation of the table can result in data loss and warns about turning of this option.

Comment: @Maxence's warning is well taken. I turned off this safety option, made my changes, then turned it back on to keep me from accidentally losing data later.

Answer (score 6):

It's a setting in SSMS.

Tools - Option - Designers - Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem; wanting to Allow Nulls for a column that previously did not.  Consider MS's warning to NOT turn off this option:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956176

And their recommendation to use Transact-SQL to solve the problem, e.g.
alter table MyTable alter column MyDate7 datetime NULL

This solved it for me.