# SQL simplist way to update an INT identity column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a column called fixedID, and it's current Value = `2`, I want to update this value to be `42`.  What is the best way to do this.  I would like to do this modification as simply as possible.  However, if I could do this while doing an select insert that would be fantastic also.

```
update tblFixedId
set FixedId = (FixedId + 400)
```

possible to change the value here?

```
Select * INTO mynewTable from myOldertable
```

Comment: Your code sample is at odds with the question body. It would set `FixedId` to 402 (assuming it is 2), not to 42. Can you please clarify if you want to update the whole table, just one row and what rule you want to use for updating?

Comment: Please explain what `tblFixedId`, `mynewTable`, `myOldertable` all are?

Answer (score 0):

Identity columns are not updatable in SQL Server.

The only way of doing this as an actual `UPDATE` rather than a `DELETE ... INSERT` would be to use `ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH` to mark the column as no longer an `IDENTITY` column, do the `UPDATE` then  `ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH` again to re-mark the column as  `IDENTITY` (For example code the first way round see the workarounds on [this Connect Item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/252226/allow-enabling-and-disabling-of-a-columns-identity-property) and for the second way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6086661/73226)).

Note that in the common scenario that the `identity` column is the clustered index key the `Update` will likely be implemented as an `INSERT ... DELETE` anyway.

Comment: Or, insert a new record with the desired ID, copy the fields and then delete the original record.  All within a transaction of course.

Comment: @Oded - What about it? It is quicker to just create the table with the desired new `identity` value as per [my example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6086661/73226)