# How to Alter a table for Identity Specification is identity SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

---

not working

```
ALTER TABLE ProductInProduct ALTER COLUMN Id KEY IDENTITY (1, 1);
```

Check Image

I have a table ProductInProduct is want its id should be Unique.. [image]

Comment: *Not working* is not a valid SQL Server error message. Btw: "*unique* and *identity* are two different concepts. Making a column an identity column does not necessarily make it unique (nor is that uniqueness enforced)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add identity to the column in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658498/how-to-add-identity-to-the-column-in-sql-server) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188278

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set auto increment after creating a table without any data loss?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084572/how-to-set-auto-increment-after-creating-a-table-without-any-data-loss). I prefer this one since it shows a way to do it that doesn't require massive amounts of data movement.

Answer (score 17):

You **cannot** "convert" an existing column into an `IDENTITY` column - you will have to create a **new column** as `INT IDENTITY`:

```
ALTER TABLE ProductInProduct 
ADD NewId INT IDENTITY (1, 1);
```

Update:

OK, so there *is* a way of converting an existing column to `IDENTITY`. If you absolutely need this - [check out this response by Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084572/sql-server-how-to-set-auto-increment-after-creating-a-table-without-data-loss/6086661#6086661) with all the gory details.

Comment: As Martin Smith is fond of pointing out, it can be done using [`SWITCH`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6086661/15498)

Comment: It's documented [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) that the IDENTITY property is not considered when using `SWITCH`. And blogged about by a Microsoft employee [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dfurman/archive/2010/04/20/adding-the-identity-property-to-a-column-of-an-existing-table.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can't alter the existing columns for identity.

You have 2 options,

Create a new table with identity & drop the existing table

Create a new column with identity & drop the existing column

Approach 1. (New table) Here you can retain the existing data values on the newly created identity column.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tmp_Names
    (
      Id int NOT NULL
             IDENTITY(1, 1),
      Name varchar(50) NULL
    )
ON  [PRIMARY]
go

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_Names ON
go

IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
            FROM    dbo.Names ) 
    INSERT  INTO dbo.Tmp_Names ( Id, Name )
            SELECT  Id,
                    Name
            FROM    dbo.Names TABLOCKX
go

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_Names OFF
go

DROP TABLE dbo.Names
go

Exec sp_rename 'Tmp_Names', 'Names'
```

Approach 2 (New column) You can’t retain the existing data values on the newly created identity column, The identity column will hold the sequence of number.

```
Alter Table Names
Add Id_new Int Identity(1, 1)
Go

Alter Table Names Drop Column ID
Go

Exec sp_rename 'Names.Id_new', 'ID', 'Column'
```

See the following Microsoft SQL Server Forum post for more details:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/04d69ee6-d4f5-4f8f-a115-d89f7bcbc032

Comment: downvote because this is copy/past of other person answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/1049305/307699

Answer (score 1):

You don't set value to default in a table. You should clear the option "Default value or Binding" first.

Comment: In fact you CAN "convert" an existing column to an IDENTITY column; but you DO need to make sure to remove any Default Value or Binding! Slangevar!