# Can we change step value of already existing identity column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can we change step value of already existing identity column ? If yes what is the maximum value?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to create a copy of the new table, populate it with data from the old table, drop the old one, rename the copy. You can see *how* this works by changing the step size in the SSMS GUI and seeing what script is produced.

The maximum step size? Based on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx), I'd guess as high as your column datatype. So don't use 4000 increment starting at 1 for a tinyint etc

Comment: You mean copy means data+schema is it?

Comment: @RajaramShelar: Use SSMS GUI to generate the script like I said. It is the *best way* to see what I mean...

Comment: No need to copy all the rows for this.

Comment: @gbn - None in my answer either.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Didn't see that. I remember this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6086661/27535 but found this older one http://stackoverflow.com/a/4848810/27535 So what next...?

Comment: @gbn - Hadn't noticed that you added a second link! Suppose I should update that now...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as a metadata only change. Example code below.

```
 --Seed Set to 1
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblFoo 
(
id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
baz INT
)


INSERT INTO dbo.tblFoo
SELECT TOP (10000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))
FROM master..spt_values v1, master..spt_values v2


--Change Seed to 7
BEGIN TRY;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    SELECT TOP 0 id 
    FROM dbo.tblFoo
    WITH (TABLOCKX,HOLDLOCK)



    DECLARE @TableScript nvarchar(max)
    SELECT @TableScript = 
    '
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Destination(
        id INT IDENTITY(' + 
                     CAST(ISNULL(IDENT_CURRENT('tblFoo'),0)+1 AS VARCHAR) + ',7)  PRIMARY KEY,
        baz INT
        )

        ALTER TABLE dbo.tblFoo SWITCH TO dbo.Destination;
    '       


    EXEC(@TableScript)


    DROP TABLE dbo.tblFoo;

    EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.Destination', N'tblFoo', 'OBJECT';


    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
END CATCH;

 INSERT INTO dbo.tblFoo 
 OUTPUT INSERTED.*     
 VALUES (1),(2)
```

Comment: @gbn - No. It doesn't use partitioning.

Comment: Are you sure? I can't test now on any SQL Server but reading MSDN again infers it is linked to partition operations

Comment: @gbn - I read somewhere that it works on all editions. I can't test that either at the moment though! Might download express and give it a shot in a bit.

Comment: @EdHarper - Thanks for confirming that. Only have developer edition accessible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Only by recreating and repopulating the table