# Identity Increment

Tags: sql-server-2008, auto-increment

**I am combining 2 tables into 1, by using the following statements**

```
Select Calls.*,Patient.*
INTO Calls2
From Calls,Patient
```

Now, i set one of the column as primary key but I cant get that primary key to have Identity Increment.
What should i do to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Madhu

Comment: It is not "denormalization" at all. It is just SQL statement. Have a read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190750.aspx  and here  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx

Comment: This is a cross join so unless one of the tables only has `<= 1` row there will be duplicate values for every column. How are you creating a PK from this?

Comment: @Martin the identity will be the PK, of course. Why would we care if the actual data is unique? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should know that you are doing a cartesian product of your tables. If you want to add an identity column when you are creating your table, then do the following:

```
Select IDENTITY(INT,1,1) ID, Calls.*,Patient.*
INTO Calls2
From Calls,Patient
```

Answer (score 1):

Perform a `CREATE TABLE` the "hard" way? You can easily build such a command from `sys.columns`.

Or set the property in Management Studio. Just be aware that this drops the table and re-creates it, so if the table is large, expect your application to lock up for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Server Management Studio

Right mouse click the table and click `Design`.  In the `Column Properties` at the bottom of the right hand window, scroll down to `Identity Specification`.  Expand this and then change the `(Is Identity)` value to `Yes`.

However, if you already have an `Id` column on the table, from either the `Calls` or `Patient` table, this may not work.  I'd suggest creating a new `Id` column and configuring the `Id` column as above.

Answer (score 0):

You can't turn an existing column into an identity column.*  If you need an identity column, add a new column:

```
ALTER TABLE Calls2 ADD Calls2Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) ;
```

Or, if you need to use one of the existing columns, you'll need to use an explicit CREATE TABLE to define the table rather than SELECT...INTO.  You'll also need to use SET IDENTITY INSERT Calls2 ON before your INSERT INTO.

```
CREATE TABLE Calls2 (
    ...columns...
) ;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Calls2 ON ;
INSERT INTO Calls2 (... columns ...) SELECT ... columns ... FROM Calls, Patient ;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Calls2 OFF ;
```

*Although the designer may pretend to turn it into an identity column, that's not actually what's happening.  As Aaron Bertrand mentions in his response, the table is being recreated with the column defined as an identity column to begin with.

Comment: [Yes you can...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084572/how-to-set-auto-increment-after-creating-a-table-without-any-data-loss/6086661#6086661)

Comment: I forgot that the designer lets you do that.  Added a note to clarify (I hope).  Thanks.

Comment: That's not what I meant because the whole table gets re-created. You can do it as a metadata only change with `ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH`