# Is there any alternative of DBCC CHECKIDENT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there any alternative (e.g. Alter Column Query) of DBCC CHECKIDENT in SQL Server?

Comment: An alternative to achieve what exactly? What are you trying to achieve and why is `DBCC CHECKIDENT` not suitable?

Comment: Actually I just wanted to set auto_increment number like this: ALTER TABLE Emp AUTO_INCREMENT=100.      But no luck

Comment: My TL dont want to use DBCC commands. Dont know why. Please suggest

Comment: Create a new table, copy over and drop the original table? Killing all the statistics in the process.

Comment: You wouldn't actually have to copy the data over. You could use [`ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6086661/73226). This would be utterly pointless though. Just use `DBCC CHECKIDENT` as that is what it is there for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try like this.

```
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MyTable] ON
INSERT INTO Mytable(ID,name)values (@AutoIncrementvalue-1,'siva')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MyTable] OFF

--Insert into table or whatever here
-- finally delete the value which we inserted initially
DELETE FROm MyTable WHERE ID=@AutoIncrementvalue-1
```

But always I prefer `DBCC CHECKIDENT`.
You may use this to satisfy your TL.

Comment: Had an issue where DBCC CHECKIDENT couldn't execute on a live environment as it couldn't get a table lock I believe so had to use the manual method above.