# add an identity column to existing table as the primary key and change order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has over 7 million records in it. The table does not have a primary key. I would like to add a new identity column and set this as the primary key. I tried adding the column using SSMS, then I set it as the primary key. I called this new column Id.

This almost worked, however I wanted to change the default order of the table to be based another column, for instance a date time column in descending order. Is this possible? Perhaps I need to use a temp table and the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

However, I am not very good at SQL. Can someone help?

I also need to have a rollback script so I can get back to the original table.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "*default order of the table*". Rows in a relational table ***ARE NOT SORTED***

Comment: @MitchWheat - approximately. Within a page, there's no guarantee that the rows are ordered per the clustered index.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - and there is no guarantee that the pages in the file are as per logical key order either.

Comment: Just noticed that you say "a date time column in descending order". So what would happen to new rows added after you have created this `IDENTITY` column anyway?

Answer (score 13):

Here is one more idea:

**Step1** - Create temporary **clustered** index on "date time column in descending order"

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_YourTableTEMP ON YourTable (DateTimeColumn DESC)
```

**Step2** - Add identity column. Now the IDs **should** be in order of previously created index - although I don't think there is 100% guarantee on this.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD IdColumn INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

**Step3** - Drop temporary index

```
DROP INDEX  ix_YourTableTEMP ON YourTable
```

**Step4** - Create new clustered PK on new column

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (IdColumn)
```

Comment: This is just an idea, it might work. To make sure the order is correct, I'd also go with creating new table.

Comment: Works perfectly for me!

Comment: didn't seem to work when the index wasn't clustered

Comment: Sadly, MSDN says `The order in which the rows are updated is not guaranteed. `

Answer (score 2):

The [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6086661/1048425) Martin Smith has given is probably the best answer, but here is an alternative:

```
-- CREATE TABLE WITH SOME DATA IN
CREATE TABLE T (X INT);
INSERT T VALUES (1), (2), (3);

-- CREATE A CLONE OF THIS TABLE, ADDING AN IDENTITY COLUMN
-- USING ORDER BY TO AFFECT THE ORDER OF THE INSERT
SELECT  ID = IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1),
        T.*
INTO    T_Clone
FROM    T
ORDER BY X DESC;

-- DROP ORIGINAL TABLE
DROP TABLE T;

-- RENAME CLONE TABLE TO ORIGINAL TABLE NAME
EXECUTE SP_RENAME 'dbo.T_Clone', 'T', 'OBJECT';

-- SELECT FROM TABLE TO CHECK RESULTS
SELECT  *
FROM    T;
```

To rollback:

```
ALTER TABLE T DROP COLUMN ID;
```

**EDIT**

It has been pointed out that `SELECT ID = IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1).. INTO.. FROM .. ORDER BY ...` does not guarantee the order of the insert. So it would appear that the fail safe option is to create your clone table using `CREATE TABLE` syntax and adding the `IDENTITY` column:

```
CREATE TABLE T_Clone
(       ID      INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        <your columns>
);
INSERT T_Clone (<your columns>)
SELECT  <your columns>
FROM    T
ORDER BY ...;
```

Then carry on with the Drop and rename as above. I can find no documentation to say this method is not reliable for ordering the insert, if it proves to still not be reliable you could use:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT T_Clone ON;
INSERT T_Clone (ID, <your columns>)
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ...),
        <your columns>
FROM    T;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT T_Clone OFF;
```

Then reseed T_CLone after the insert.

Comment: It certainly hasn't always been so that `SELECT ... INTO ... ORDER BY` respects that order for generating the identity values. See e.g. [KB273586](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/273586)

Comment: Your update is fine AFAIK as per [point 4 here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2005/07/20/441053.aspx).