# Modify the identity specification of primary key in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

[image]I have table "Categories" where primary key is "categoryId". Initially, I made a mistake and did not set identity specification to 'yes'. now I have other tables where 'categoryId' is using as foreign key. I have to identity specification to 'yes' but SQL Server 2005 is not allowing me.

**Is there any other option to set it 'yes' except create script for whole database and then make new 'Categories' table?**

I also tried to remove primary key from this column but then its saying me that child tables will be deleted.

I tried [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column/) also but its not upto my request.

Comment: Did you try doing this in the table design?

Comment: I mean, through the Properties window-setting Identity specification to Yes?

Comment: @Aishvarya: yes, by going to column properties window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084572/how-to-set-auto-increment-after-creating-a-table-without-any-data-loss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this .
go to sql server management studio then :
tools -> options -> designers -> Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation (uncheck this )

after this try again to set identity column

Comment: You will lose all of the data if you do this.

Comment: @Light : SQL server is not showing me even that option (Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation) by going tools -> options -> designers ->

Comment: @NeilKnight not this will not affect the data.

Comment: @Sohail you have sql server management studio installed ? and you can not see this option ?

Comment: @Light: SQL is not showing [this highlighted](http://hellowahab.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/disable-prevent-re-creation.png) in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If loosing data is no problem means you can retry it by deleting data from your table.

Comment: yup, will try by making dummy database. thnx