# Auto Increment in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an existing database, with a table `Categories`, where I have a primary key on a column `id`. I have a lot of rows in my database, so I don't want to make it from the beginning.

I forgot when I was creating it to do AUTO_INCREMENT in `Categories`, so now I try to update it, but I get an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'MODIFY'.

This is my code

```
ALTER TABLE Categories MODIFY id INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Does anyone know what I do wrong?

Comment: auto_increment is mysql? sql server it's identity.

Answer (score 2):

First create a new identity column called ID2

```
ALTER TABLE CATEGORIES
ADD COLUMN ID2 INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL;
```

Then populate it with values from ID

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT CATEGORIES ON; -- thanks Mathese

UPDATE C
SET ID2 = ID
FROM CATEGORIES C
ORDER BY ID ASC;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT CATEGORIES OFF;
```

Once your ID values are safely migrated over to the new ID2 column, drop ID.

```
ALTER TABLE CATEGORIES
DROP COLUMN ID;
GO -- I think you may have to do GO here.
```

Then, rename ID2 to ID.

```
EXEC SP_RENAME @OBJNAME = 'CATEGORIES.ID2', @NEWNAME = 'ID', @OBJTYPE = 'COLUMN';
```

Comment: When you will do the update you will receive an error because you cannot update an identity column unless specifying set identity_insert on categories

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE categories 
   ADD ID INT IDENTITY
```

and then you can make it as primary key

```
ALTER TABLE categories 
   ADD CONSTRAINT PK_categories
   PRIMARY KEY(ID)
```

Comment: i get Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'ID' in table 'Categories' is specified more than once.

Comment: i already have it definied, so i can't do that

Comment: You cannot add identity to an existing column. Best you can do is create a new Identity column (ID2) then copy data over from the ID column... drop ID column then rename ID2 to ID.  Or you can follow this link http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1397/add-or-drop-identity-property-for-an-existing-sql-server-column/

Comment: @samyi - ahem. It *can* be done without having to mess about with the data - you can use the [partitioning features](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084572/how-to-set-auto-increment-after-creating-a-table-without-any-data-loss/6086661#6086661)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, thanks for the headsup on that... fantastic!