# How to add identity to column that exist in table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stamp_Merchandise](
    [merch_id] [float] NULL,
    [merch_desc] [nvarchar](255) NULL,

) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Im trying to alter the column merch_id by adding identity(1,1)
but i keep getting error:

```
  alter table Stamp_Merchandise 
  alter column merch_id  identity(1,1)
```

error:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'identity'.

I'm using sql server 2012.

Comment: You can't like that. And float columns can't be `identity` anyway. Does the table have data in it?

Comment: yes it does , what i really want to do make that collum auto increment

Comment: Do you need to preserve the identity values in the existing rows or can the new values be arbitrarily assigned?

Comment: you can't make a float field identity; identity columns must be of data type int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, or decimal or numeric with a scale of 0

Comment: @hex494d49 so if i change it to int it can work ?

Comment: No there's no syntax like that to add identity to an existing column. [It is possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084572/sql-server-how-to-set-auto-increment-after-creating-a-table-without-data-loss/6086661#6086661) but given the datatype change you may well be best off just rebuilding the table anyway.

Comment: As said above, you can't alter the existing columns for identity; create a new column with identity and drop the existing one. Or create a new table with identity

Comment: Create a new table with same schema, except make `[merch_id]` INT data type and Identity column, SET identity_insert on, Insert all the data from your existing table into new table, drop this old table and rename the new table to this table name and your are good.

Comment: Also dont forget to run DBCC reseed commands to reseed the identity values.

Comment: thanks ,what i actually end up doing was create another table and insert ect. , it work thanks