# i get this error. how to solve this error?

Tags: php, sql-server

> Warning : odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'to'., SQL state
>   37000 in SQLExecDirect in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\lendkarma\dashboard\viewpost.php

```
<?php
if($userconnection)
    {
       $sql_result="INSERT into blogs_new(empid,blog_title,status,blog_author) VALUES ($empid,$title,$a,$status,$author)";
       echo $sql_result;
       $res=odbc_exec($userconnection,$sql_result);
     // $res = odbc_prepare($userdatabase,"INSERT INTO t_blogs (empid,blog_title,blog_content,status,blog_author) VALUES ($empid,$title,$a,$status,$author)");
    }
    else
    {
       echo "connection error";
    }
?>
```

Comment: <?phpif($userconnection)
 {
    $sql_result="INSERT into blogs_new(empid,blog_title,status,blog_author) VALUES ($empid,$title,$a,$status,$author)";
    echo $sql_result;
    $res=odbc_exec($userconnection,$sql_result);
  // $res = odbc_prepare($userdatabase,"INSERT INTO t_blogs (empid,blog_title,blog_content,status,blog_author) VALUES ($empid,$title,$a,$status,$author)");
 }
 else
 {
    echo "connection error";
 }
?>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should add some apostrophe around your string type of value in your sql query string.
Something like this.

```
$sql_result="INSERT into blogs_new(empid,blog_title,status,blog_author) VALUES ('".$empid."','".$title."','".$a."','".$status."','".$author."')";
```

Comment: Warning:  odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'blog_id', table 'lend_user.dbo.blog'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails., SQL state 23000 in SQLExecDirect in C:\xampp\htdocs\lendkarma\dashboard\viewpost.php

Comment: Maybe it is because your SQL table has a blog_id column, that is not auto increment but not allows null and the query dont set that value.
Try to change the column to auto increment.

Comment: Update blogs SET empid='',blog_title='',blog_content='',blog_author='' WHERE blog_id = 
Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '='., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in C:\xampp\htdocs\lendkarma\dashboard\editpost.php on line 16

Comment: I mean the table definition not the record. Please check this. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084572/sql-server-how-to-set-auto-increment-after-creating-a-table-without-data-loss

Answer (score -1):

Your values need quotes around them:

```
$sql_result="INSERT into blogs_new(empid,blog_title,status,blog_author) VALUES ('$empid','$title','$a','$status','$author')";
```

Comment: connected successfully..
Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '='., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in C:\xampp\htdocs\lendkarma\dashboard\action\update_post.php on line 30
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: how to fix this issues plz help me