# add auto_increment to an existing db

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL. I created a table and filled it with some data. Now I want to change the properties of my primary key, so it will auto increment every single time by itself when adding data.

I know how to do it when creating a table, but where do I add auto_increment now, when I already have a created table with filled data?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

Try

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName] DROP COLUMN ID 
ALTER TABLE [TableName] ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

If you had entered data to your table review this link that have an answer to you question [SQL Server, How to set auto increment after creating a table without data loss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084572/sql-server-how-to-set-auto-increment-after-creating-a-table-without-data-loss)

Comment: If you had entered data to your table review this link that have an answer to you question [SQL Server, How to set auto increment after creating a table without data loss?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084572/sql-server-how-to-set-auto-increment-after-creating-a-table-without-data-loss)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change logical structure column when you have some filled data in column. That's impossible. You must deleting data from column and use `ALTER TABLE` to change properites column

Comment: @Faizy This all depends on the DBMD being used. This is very well possible e.g. in Postgres