# Transfering from MS Access to SQL Server primary key - identity

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I transferred a MS Access database to SQL Server. It appears that all data was transferred.

The primary key values were placed it the appropriate columns and can be found by there value. 
However I can not add a new row to that table. My research says that the problem is that there is no identity property added to this column. As these primary keys and identity field need to be the same number. Identity_insert ?

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to add a new row? I'm guessing the column that used to be your identity in Access is not  an identity column in SQL Server. You'll need to recreate the "identity" column because you can't enable identity on an existing column. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288222/how-do-i-add-the-identity-property-to-an-existing-column-in-sql-server

Comment: If you have the primary keys like in Access then why do you need identity? Do you want identity or not?